# Azure node IOT SDK how to set callbacks for MQTT exceptions

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have used the Azure IOT SDK for C in several projects.  There's pretty good documentation and it's clear how to register a callback to be notified if a message cannot be sent, or if the MQTT connection drops.  Looking over the javascript SDK for node, I can't figure out how to register similar callbacks.  For example, after creating the client I can call `client.open(onConnect)`and the `onConnect` method is called when the connection is established.  I can also call `client.sendEvent(message,...)` to send a message, and if successful am notified that the message is queued.  However:

- How do I register a callback to be notified if the mqtt connection is interrupted?
- How do I register a callback to be told if a packet is successfully received (QOS 1 or 2) or fails to send?
- How do I specify level of QOS that I would like?

Thanks

Comment: for some your questions, have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, few points to note regarding MQTT QoS support in IoT hub:

> - IoT Hub does not support QoS 2 messages. If a device app publishes a message with QoS 2, IoT Hub closes the network connection. When a
>   device app subscribes to a topic with QoS 2, IoT Hub grants maximum
>   QoS level 1 in the SUBACK packet. After that, IoT Hub delivers
>   messages to the device using QoS 1.
> - By default, the device SDKs connect to an IoT Hub with QoS 1 for message exchange with the IoT hub.

For details, refer [Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support).

Now coming to the question, you have 2 options:

### Using Azure IoT SDK:

If you want to use [IoT hub device sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node), below is one reference from [official sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js) which handles disconnection scenario. Regarding QoS 1 related exchange (like PUBACK confirmation), it does not allow at lower level, but handles internally to ensure guaranteed message delivery. For directly using MQTT, refer later part of my answer.

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

'use strict';

const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
// Uncomment one of these transports and then change it in fromConnectionString to test other transports
// const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').AmqpWs;
// const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-http').Http;
// const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').Amqp;
// const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').MqttWs;
const Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
const Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

// String containing Hostname, Device Id & Device Key in the following formats:
//  "HostName=<iothub_host_name>;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessKey=<device_key>"
const deviceConnectionString = process.env.DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING;
let sendInterval;

function disconnectHandler () {
  clearInterval(sendInterval);
  client.open().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
}

// The AMQP and HTTP transports have the notion of completing, rejecting or abandoning the message.
// For example, this is only functional in AMQP and HTTP:
// client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
// If using MQTT calls to complete, reject, or abandon are no-ops.
// When completing a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message has been processed.
// When rejecting a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message won't be processed by the device. the method to use is client.reject(msg, callback).
// When abandoning the message, IoT Hub will immediately try to resend it. The method to use is client.abandon(msg, callback).
// MQTT is simpler: it accepts the message by default, and doesn't support rejecting or abandoning a message.
function messageHandler (msg) {
  console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);
  client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
}

function generateMessage () {
  const windSpeed = 10 + (Math.random() * 4); // range: [10, 14]
  const temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 10); // range: [20, 30]
  const humidity = 60 + (Math.random() * 20); // range: [60, 80]
  const data = JSON.stringify({ deviceId: 'myFirstDevice', windSpeed: windSpeed, temperature: temperature, humidity: humidity });
  const message = new Message(data);
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 28) ? 'true' : 'false');
  return message;
}

function errorCallback (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}

function connectCallback () {
  console.log('Client connected');
  // Create a message and send it to the IoT Hub every two seconds
  sendInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const message = generateMessage();
    console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
    client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('send'));
  }, 2000);

}

// fromConnectionString must specify a transport constructor, coming from any transport package.
let client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);

client.on('connect', connectCallback);
client.on('error', errorCallback);
client.on('disconnect', disconnectHandler);
client.on('message', messageHandler);

client.open()
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
});

// Helper function to print results in the console
function printResultFor(op) {
  return function printResult(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
    if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
  };
}
```

### Using MQTT Directly:

As mentioned in [Using the MQTT protocol directly (as a device)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device), you can also connect to the public device endpoints using the MQTT protocol on port 8883. For that you can use any standard MQTT library available (for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt). However, note the below for some special consideration:

> In the CONNECT packet, the device should use the following values:
>
> - For the ClientId field, use the deviceId.
> - For the Username field, use {iothubhostname}/{device_id}/?api-version=2018-06-30, where
>   {iothubhostname} is the full CName of the IoT hub. For example, if the
>   name of your IoT hub is contoso.azure-devices.net and if the name of
>   your device is MyDevice01, the full Username field should contain: `contoso.azure-devices.net/MyDevice01/?api-version=2018-06-30`
> - For the Password field, use a SAS token. The format of the SAS token is the same as for both the HTTPS and AMQP protocols: `SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}`

> Note
>
> If you use X.509 certificate authentication, SAS token passwords are
> not required. For more information, see [Set up X.509 security in your
> Azure IoT
> Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started)
> and follow code instructions in the [TLS/SSL configuration
> section](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#tlsssl-configuration).
>
> For more information about how to generate SAS tokens, see the device
> section of [Using IoT Hub security
> tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#use-sas-tokens-in-a-device-app).

Comment: Thank you!  When sending a message, if the callback receives a success does that imply a QOS 1 receipt, that is, the IOT hub as acknowledged receiving the message? (as opposed to the SDK acknowledging receiving the message and putting it into its send queue, as happens with the C SDK).

Comment: Yes. If the callback in `client.sendEvent` receives success that would mean IoT hub have received (but not necessarily someone else in the receiver side of IoT hub has further received it yet from IoT hub).